# ¿Cómo relacionar el contenido de una función con la función y construirlo en un árbol con lark?

Tags: python, sintaxis, parsear, tree, parser

Estoy practicando con la librería lark para hacer un parser para visualizar de forma resumida y estructurada código python y quiero que al identificar el patrón de una función "def" me haga un **árbol** con:

1. Nombre de la función
2. Argumentos de la función
3. Contenido de la función

El **resultado** que quiero obtener es:

```
new_function
    function_name    "nombre de la función"
    args             "argumentos de la función"
    content          
                     "contenido de la función"
```

Para esto, lo he hecho primero por separado (sin relacionar el contenido con la función) y luego he mirado la documentación de lark para ver como podía hacer para conseguir el texto indentado después de la función.

He encontrado el siguiente ejemplo [código](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/indented_tree.html), el cual crea un árbol según la indentación del texto. He intentado aplicarlo a mi código pero a la mínima que intentaba ajustarlo a mis necesidades ya me daba error.

El código del ejemplo está únicamente creado para la indentación y quiero que también funcione para mostrar asignaciones de variables, llamadas a funciones, expresiones booleanas, etc.

## Código

```
from lark import Lark

grammar=r'''start: expr

?expr: atom
         | expr def_function
         | expr function
         | expr ("=" | ":=")    -> assignment
         | expr "+" atom        -> add
         | expr "-" atom        -> minus
         | expr bool atom
         | expr args            -> args
         | expr "," atom
         | expr ":" atom
         | expr "(" expr ")" atom
         | expr STRING atom

?atom: NUMBER           -> number
    | NAME "(" expr ")" -> function
    | STRING -> string
    | variable
    | "(" expr ")"      -> tuple
    | empty

def_function: "def" func_name "(" args ")" ":" NEWLINE -> new_function
function: NAME "(" expr ")" -> function
func_name: NAME

args: empty
    | NAME

operation: "+"      -> add
    | "-"           -> minus
    | "*"           -> mul
    | "/"           -> division

bool: "=="          -> is_equal
    | "<"           -> is_shorter
    | ">"           -> is_bigger
    | "<="          -> is_shorter_or_equal
    | ">="          -> is_bigger_or_equal

empty: "()" | "[]" | "{}"
variable: NAME

%import common.CNAME -> NAME
%import common.NUMBER
%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING
%import common.NEWLINE
%import common._INDENT -> INDENT
%import common.WS
%ignore WS'''
test_code='''x=(2+1<0)
print("x", a)
def hi(car, r):
    t="hi"
print()
'''

parser = Lark(grammar, start='expr')
print(parser.parse(test_code).pretty())
```

## Output

Como veis, al principio se repite un montón de veces args, assignment y expr; como podría hacer para reducirlo (esas filas no indican ni una expresión, ni una asignación ni nada, tiene que ser un fallo del código)

```
args
    expr
      assignment
           expr
             expr
               args
                 expr
                   assignment
                     variable        x
                   bool
                     add
                       number        2
                       number        1
                     is_shorter
                     number  0
                   function
                     print
                     expr
                       string        "x"
                       variable      a
                 args        def
               function
                 hi
                 expr
                   variable  car
                   variable  r
             variable        t
         "hi"
         variable    print
       args
         empty
```

## Resultado esperado

```
# x=(2+1<0)
assignment
                variable        x
                bool
                        add
                                number  2
                                number  1
                        is_shorter
                        number  0
# print("x", a)
function
        print
        args
                string          "x"
                variable        a
# def hi(car, r):
    # t="hi"
new_function
        function_name   hi
        args
                variable        car
                variable        r
        content
                assignment
                        variable        t
                        string          "hi"
# print()
function        print
        args    empty
```